# Is it possible to trigger the jQuery Autocomplete plugin on "paste"?

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I have a jQuery Autocomplete plugin and when I copy/paste into it, it doesn't trigger. Any way to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#ID').bind('paste', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#ID').trigger('autocomplete');}, 0);
});
```

Comment: This isn't triggering the autocomplete

Comment: This will not trigger autocomplete if you paste the same data. qbantek's solution will do.

Comment: This code detects the paste event but it doesn't fire the autocomplete on paste for me.

Comment: This is not working for me either.
For years i have this problem with JQuery AC that works only once with paste after the page loads. After that, any paste will not fire the autocomplete. I need to manually click on space, sometimes twice to get it to fire.

Answer (score 14):

```
$("#ID").bind("paste", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#ID").autocomplete("search", $("#ID").val());
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Note this should be placed after initializing the autocomplete. Else this won't work.

Comment: Not working for me.
1st paste after the page loads always works.
Any other paste requires a manual space or two to get AC to fire...

Even running $("#ID").autocomplete("search", $("#ID").val()); in console manually does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For me to get this to work, I have to bind a keydown event. This caused the field to appear modified and the autocomplete executed.

```
$('#ID').bind('paste', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {$('#ID').trigger('keydown');}, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ID').bind('input propertychange'), function(){
    //do what you want here 
});
```